In WinUI 3 DataGrid tab key not working properly
When i was single click on particular column and press tab key then it will focus on column header not next column. How i will resolved it.

<controls:DataGrid x:Name="grid" CanUserSortColumns="True" SelectionMode="Extended"
                    Height="326" Width="1660" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" FontSize="10" GridLinesVisibility="All"
                    ColumnHeaderHeight="25" RowBackground="White" TabFocusNavigation="Cycle" TabNavigation="Cycle"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
<controls:DataGridTextColumn Width="20" Binding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="10"/>
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="PG" Tag="PG" Width="44">
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding RPe,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="45" MinHeight="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                     Margin="8 -4 0 0" Padding="20 5 0 0" FontSize="10" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="P" Width="174" CanUserSort="True" Tag="Part" >
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0,0,15">
                <TextBlock x:Name="pnum" Text="{Binding Pnum, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="10" 
                         VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black">
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>


You can capture the PreviewKeyDown event and apply your custom behavior.
<controls:DataGrid PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown" ... />

private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key is not VirtualKey.Tab ||
        sender is not DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        return;
    }

    int nextColumnIndex = dataGrid.Columns.IndexOf(dataGrid.CurrentColumn);
    nextColumnIndex += 1;

    if (nextColumnIndex >= dataGrid.Columns.Count)
    {
        nextColumnIndex = 0;
        
        // Should be faster if you can get the count directly from the source.
        int itemsCount = dataGrid.ItemsSource.Cast<object>().Count();

        int nextRowIndex = dataGrid.SelectedIndex + 1;
        dataGrid.SelectedIndex = nextRowIndex < itemsCount
            ? nextRowIndex
            : 0;
    }

    if (dataGrid.Columns.ElementAtOrDefault(nextColumnIndex) is not { } column)
    {
        return;
    }

    dataGrid.CurrentColumn = column;
    e.Handled = true;
}


Thanks that are work for me. But I also need focus or select textbox or value which have focus and if tab is in combox then that will work on space key to open list. Those thinks not working.

That also move only same row not moving next row.

Updated the answer so the focus goes to the next row.

For the extended question (TextBox and ComoboBox), I guess it's better if you could ask it on a new question.

Sure. But thanks, I got 90% solution of my problem because of you. thanks
